# Does spectacle user able to guess correct distance of object?

Tags: lenses, vision

It is said in many numericals like a man has near point 100 cm than he need a convex lens that can project a img of obj kept at 25cm at 100cm so that he can watch it clearly!
Then my question is,
Does the spects user will imagine tge obj at 100cm? Or 25cm? How he would be able to pridict actual distance of object?
Same with concave lens it say it form img of infinity at far point like 1m so where i able to predict distance at infinity or far point?
I mean that whether the far sightedness patient of near point 100cm will able to see object kept at 25cm, whether he will see it at 25 or 100 cm as many numericals said that " a lens require that form img at near point of that person so that he can see and bla bla bla"?
If yes than how he is able to catch or hold things properly if the position at which he see obj is just virtual formed by lens?

Answer (score 1):

All of us gauge distances to objects in our vicinity not by focus but by *binocular parallax*, where the brain uses the left-to-right image shift produced by your two eyes to triangulate the distance to the object upon which you have fixed your gaze.

This is true even for people wearing corrective glasses and for people who wear glasses but take them off.

Comment: So brain fixes the actual distance???

Comment: all that figuring is done IN THE BRAIN.

Comment: Although some people (e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesley_Walker) do fine with essentially one eye. If I recall properly he would shake his head to slightly vary the angle with his one good eye to get the distance.